# What happens when supplying an LED with too low voltage?

Tags: led

What happens when supplying an LED with too low voltage? Will it just emit less light? I'm making an octocopter, and need to cut away as much weight as possible. I need to run the LED without cooling if possible.

Comment: Which LED? Where is the data spec and how much voltage are you going/wanting to supply?

Comment: There is no data spec other than 50W at 33 to 36 V.

Comment: You mean the one supplier you've found doesn't say what it is publicly. There is always a data spec.

Comment: @deed02392 Exactly! Do you mean that the data spec should describe everything in my question?

Comment: The manufacturer will certainly have written and published a data spec., although you might need to contact the supplier for a copy. But this way you'll know exactly what voltage you can get away with and probably even the relative luminosity (as a % of max given full voltage) with your chosen voltage. This could help you decide on an LED that's designed for lower voltage in the first place that can be just as bright.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at a typical LED forward bias graph: -

[image]

Y axis is current and x axis is voltage. At about 2V the LED takes 20mA and illuminates nicely. At 2.2V the current has shot-up to nearly 40mA and the LED is bright.

At 1.8V the current is about 5mA and the LED is a bit dim. At 1.6V or below the LED hardly takes any current and probably will barely be visible in a dark room.

Below this there is no business until you start going negative then at about -5V applied the LED usually dies, never to recover.

This is a typical old-fashioned red LED and, may not 100% apply to more modern LEDs exactly/verbatim but the general idea is the same.

Answer (score 3):

There are two questions here, which each deserve an an answer:

**Question 1: What happens if you supply an LED with a lower voltage than it was designed for?**

LEDs are sold with a standard operating supply voltage (i.e., forward voltage). This is the voltage the LEDs were designed to be operated at, and at this voltage they will perform within the stated specs: amount of light produced  (lumens), current draw (amps), and power (watts). Importantly, this is also the voltage at which the recommended heat dissipation will keep the LED cool enough (within its operating temperatures).

When the supplied voltage is greater than the operating voltage, it has a range of impacts on the led.

- More current will flow
- More light will be produced
- More waste heat will be produced

from a more practical persepective, the light will become brighter and hotter until it fails, either due to thermal failure (typical) or due to electrical failure/short (usually at higher voltages).

At lower voltages, the light will become dimmer and generate less heat, until no light is produced and no current is consumed (typically at around 1.5-1.8v for common 3mm leds). This point is usuallynear the "voltage drop" of the LED as listed on the spec sheet.

At negative voltages, the LED produce no light and will fail electrically (typically -5V or so).

These relationships are not linear however, and have some interesting second order effects:

- LEDs are more efficient (more lumens produced per watt of power consumed) at lower voltages
- LEDS are more efficient at lower temperatures
- LEDS lifespan is longer at lower temperatures

[image: Luminous flux v vs. current i f for different junction temperatures: the stars indicate values from datasheet at T j = T ⇤ = 298.1 K; other curves represent (8) for different values of T j ; the filled circles (with the corresponding interpolating curve) indicate the luminous flux v calculated with (8) for different currents and T j obtained from (6) at steady-state. Reproduced from: Model Predictive Control for Luminous Flux Tracking in Light-Emitting Diodes by Silvio Baccari, Francesco Vasca, Massimo Tipaldi, Luigi Iannelli (2016)]

These relationships can be seen in the figure above, which show that lumens produced increase with current, but decrease with temperature. The lines are not straight - meaning the light produced per watt of power decreases at higher currents.

This has resulted in some interesting engineering solutions, like the Phillips "Dubai Bulbs" which operate at roughly 1/4 the typical power per LED, in order to achieve very high efficiency and very long lifespans. https://hackaday.com/2021/01/17/leds-from-dubai-the-royal-lights-you-cant-buy/

**Question 2: How can I minimize the weight that LED lighting adds to my drone**

As general advice, you can get the lightest-possible solution using some simple principles:

1. Use the smallest size LEDs that you find acceptable (50W is very large for a drone - would 10W work instead?)
2. Wire the LEDs to use the same voltage as other onboard systems, so that you don't need any additional power management circuitry
3. LEDs are cheap, and you don't need long lifespan - so don't worry too much about keeping temperatures very low
4. Trim off any excess material and keep wire leads as short as possible.
5. If you can, position the LED in the downdraft from a motor as Matija suggested and/or use another part of the frame as the heatsink, such as an aluminum standoff. You could use a small amount of thermal epoxy or a small strip of adhesive LED strip to adhere it.

All that said, LEDs likely contribute very little to your overall drone weight - the best places to look for weight reductions are likely other areas (battery choice, wiring, frame, motors). Always look for low hanging fruit first!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have mentioned the word cooling I assume you must be talking about a power LED. Standard LEDs generally do not require cooling. A power LED dissipates roughly 1/3 of the energy supplied to it as heat. Therefore it is possible to reduce the heat dissipation of the LED and hence the need for a heatsink by reducing the power supplied to the LED.

Comment: I don't know what the LED is called but it's a 50W LED...

Answer (score 1):

As others say, it will depend on that LED datasheet. 50W is pretty big, I doubt you'd be able to run that LED without cooling. Also, you'll want limit the brightness (and power usage / heating) of the power LED with current limiter (eg. driving it with constant current source) or with PWM, not by lowering voltage (LEDs do not behave the same as your typical lightbulb!)

And/or you could always use lower specd LED (with less power drawn, less heating, and of course less light produced).

Alternatively, as it is for octocopter, I'd guess you have 8 pretty good active cooling parts already, maybe you can use them to cool the LED instead of the big passive heatsink on it (just a small one + wind generated by propellers through it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I ended up having four LEDs, placed underneath the propellers as you suggested. It works very well.